# Distributed build systems BuildXL vs IncrediBuild

Tags: build, distributed, incredibuild

BuildXL vs IncrediBuild.

Could someone clearly explain the difference between the two options for building code distributable on Windows? Is it either/or sort or they can stack up to be are complementary to each other to build even faster?

Answer (score 0):

Incredibuild is highly focused on accelerating large C++ code bases and is directly integrated in Visual Studio. It supports various build systems such as MSBuild, CMake, Make, Ninja, Gcc and more.
According to BuildXL GitHub page: "There are currently no plans to integrate it into Visual Studio."
It supports JavaScript and has some experimental and beta support for other build systems

Comment: ... but VSCode?: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=BuildXL.dscript ... odd.